# WPF binding TextBox and ObservableDictionary<Int64,String> (display String by Id)

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Each item of my Employee's list has `Post` property. This property is `Int64` type. Also, I have some `ObservableDictionary<Int64,String>` as static property. Each Employe must display the `String` value by its key.
DataTemplate for `Employe` item (I deleted the superfluous):

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="tmpEmploye">
            <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="5">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">                        
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Post}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>                               
        </DataTemplate>
```

But this code displayed the `Int64` value, not the `String`. String for getting static dictionary:

```
"{Binding Source={x:Static app:Program.Data}, Path=Posts}"
```

I know how solve it problem for `ComboBox`, but I don't know for `TextBlock`. For `ComboBox` I wrote it (it is works fine):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboPost" x:FieldModifier="public" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static app:Program.Data}, Path=Posts}" DisplayMemberPath="Value"
          SelectedValuePath="Key"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Post, Mode=TwoWay}">            
</ComboBox>
```

But how can I solve it for `TextBlock`?

Comment: @Blam notified about dictionary changes. Its signature: `ObservableDictionary<TKey,TValue> : NotifyPropertyChangedClass, INotifyCollectionChanged, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> where TKey: IEquatable<TKey>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mmmmm, I'm sure I have developed something for this scenario before but I can't remember or find anything related!

IMO you can use a converter, so you pass your Post (Int64) to the converter and it returns the string value from the dictionary, although it must be a better solution.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Int64), typeof(string))]    
public class PostToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // validation code, etc
        return (from p in YourStaticDictionary where p.Key == Convert.ToInt64(value) select p.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:YourConverterNamespace"
    ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <l:PostToStringConverter x:Key="converter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Post, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Yes, I can. But maybe exists more simple method, without IValueConvereter? It is interesting for me.

Comment: you can create a string property on Employee and inject the right value.

Comment: I think the nicer way is to implement the converter. This way the view models are not affected.